# How to stop EmberJs from change hash URL

Tags: ember.js

I have a user submission form if user make any changes in the form, user should submit form to save the change in persistent data base. Page has other links, when user clicks on the link without submission the changes. I have to stop the user to redirection and show the modal box message to convey the message.

I tried below method but does not work.

```
    App.FormRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
       actions: {
          willTransition: function(transition) {
            if (this.controller.get('userHasEnteredData')) {
               transition.abort();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your solution works fine, you can see [working demo](https://ember-twiddle.com/206cdc24b51f446b5c6d). Just make sure haven't misspelled any variable name during set in controller or read in form route.

Comment: I am not using {{#link-to}} instead using <a href="#/route">

Comment: Well, you shouldn't be doing that, it's against Ember. You should switch to `link-to`, because if you go against Ember you can't expect all Ember functionality working properly for you, and this is the case for you.